# arch-linux qtile keybinds no reaction

Tags: config, archlinux, window-managers

Installed qtile x manager on ArchLinux OS. Got it from repository. Installed needed packages:

pycairo-xcb-git
xorg-xpyb-git
qtile-git

Qtile started. Show information on bottom panel (version of config, time, etc.)
But there is no reaction on default keybinds (for example open XTerm).

Qtile have any log files, or any?

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention the log file like if you are using .xinitrc to start qtile:

> exec qtile >> ~/.qtile.log

this will open qtile as well as write the output to .qtile.log; you will not originally have this file, so create one :

> cat > ~/.qtile.log